# "A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree"

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

In using the **EntityFramework**, I get the error "`A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree`" when trying to compile the following code:

```
Obj[] myArray = objects.Select(o =>
{
    var someLocalVar = o.someVar;

    return new Obj() { 
    Var1 = someLocalVar,
    Var2 = o.var2 };
}).ToArray();
```

I don't know what the error means and most of all how to fix it. Any help?

Comment: try to convert to to list like this. objects.List().Select(...

Answer (score 155):

Is `objects` a Linq-To-SQL database context? In which case, you can only use simple expressions to the right of the => operator. The reason is, these expressions are not executed, but are converted to SQL to be executed against the database.
Try this

```
Arr[] myArray = objects.Select(o => new Obj() { 
    Var1 = o.someVar,
    Var2 = o.var2 
}).ToArray();
```

Comment: OK but what if I'm working with a single object instead of an IEnumerable? It becomes tricky : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50837875/ienumerable-select-for-a-single-item

Answer (score 131):

You can use statement body in lamba expression for **IEnumerable** collections.
try this one:

```
Obj[] myArray = objects.AsEnumerable().Select(o =>
{
    var someLocalVar = o.someVar;

    return new Obj() 
    { 
        Var1 = someLocalVar,
        Var2 = o.var2 
    };
}).ToArray();
```

**Notice:**
Think carefully when using this method, because this way, you will have all query results in the application's memory, that may have unwanted side effects on the rest of your code.

Comment: +1 I like this! Adding `AsEnumerable()` maskes my problem go away!

Comment: This is the real solution, the accepted answer is difficult to apply in some cases

Comment: No this is not the real answer. It would make your query to be executed on client side. Refer to this question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375998/optimize-linq-to-sql-statement-that-has-foreign-key-access/33376119

Comment: @DatVM it depends on what you are going to do. this can not be always right choice and of course can not be always wrong choice.

Comment: Though I agree with you, the OP stated that he was using EntityFramework. Most of the case, when working with EF, you want the database-side to do as much work as possible. It would be nice if you note the case in your answer.

Comment: This worked for me too. Adding the AsEnumerable() function allowed me to inject the converted Var property into the underlying object without declaring "new".

Comment: Since nobody appears to have pointed this out... this is not a lambda expression, it's a `Func`.

Comment: Since IQueryable is already IEnumerable, do you know why the correct overload for Select - the one that accepts a delegate/Func<> - was not automatically chosen?

Comment: @AmirOveisi can you extend your "notice" sentence with the extra words "executed on client side"? I thought the words "all query result in memory" were referring to SQL db memory use.

Answer (score 45):

It means that you can't use lambda expressions with a "statement body" (i.e. lambda expressions which use curly braces) in places where the lambda expression needs to be converted to an expression tree (which is for example the case when using linq2sql).

Comment: You... slightly rephrased the error. @Tim Rogers' answer was much better

Comment: @vbullinger you're right to a degree, but in a more general sense (outside the context of linq-to-sql) this is a more direct answer. It helped me with an AutoMapper error

Comment: vbullinger: It did help me, though.

Comment: vbullinger: I got this error without it being a Linq-To-SQL issue.

Comment: provide an answer please !

Answer (score 7):

Without knowing more about what you are doing (Linq2Objects, Linq2Entities, Linq2Sql?), this should make it work:

```
Arr[] myArray = objects.AsEnumerable().Select(o => {
    var someLocalVar = o.someVar;

    return new Obj() { 
        Var1 = someLocalVar,
        Var2 = o.var2 
    }; 
}).ToArray();
```

Comment: This forces the queryable to evaluate.

Comment: However, in this circumstance it is okay, because he calls ToArray() right after anyway.

Comment: not necessarily -- who knows how big "o" is?  it could have 50 properties when all we want are 2.

Comment: When using this technique, I like to select the fields I will use into an anonymous type before calling `.AsEnumerable()`

Answer (score 7):

The LINQ to SQL return object were implementing `IQueryable` interface. So for `Select` method predicate parameter you should only supply single lambda expression without body.

This is because LINQ for SQL code is not execute inside program rather than on remote side like SQL server or others. This lazy loading execution type were achieve by implementing IQueryable where its expect delegate is being wrapped in Expression type class like below.

```
Expression<Func<TParam,TResult>>
```

Expression tree do not support  lambda expression with body and its only support single line lambda expression like `var id = cols.Select( col => col.id );`

So if you try the following code won't works.

```
Expression<Func<int,int>> function = x => {
    return x * 2;
}
```

The following will works as per expected.

```
Expression<Func<int,int>> function = x => x * 2;
```

Answer (score 6):

9 years too late to the party, but a different approach to your problem (that nobody has mentioned?):

The statement-body works fine with `Func<>` but won't work with `Expression<Func<>>`. `IQueryable.Select` wants an `Expression<>`, because they can be translated for Entity Framework - `Func<>` can not.

So you either use the `AsEnumerable` and start working with the data in memory (not recommended, if not really neccessary) or you keep working with the `IQueryable<>` which is recommended.
There is something called `linq query` which makes some things easier:

```cs
IQueryable<Obj> result = from o in objects
                         let someLocalVar = o.someVar
                         select new Obj
                         {
                           Var1 = someLocalVar,
                           Var2 = o.var2
                         };
```

with `let` you can define a variable and use it in the `select` (or `where`,...) - and you keep working with the `IQueryable` until you really need to execute and get the objects.

Afterwards you can `Obj[] myArray = result.ToArray()`

Comment: I just looked this up! Wish you could have seen the intrigue on my face when i saw a 9 year old post have a "A new answer has been added to this post". Hahaha  Nice timing.

Comment: @TeaBaerd haha yeah. :D coincidences are funny sometimes...

Comment: how to include nested tables in linq? do i have to use join /

Comment: @Ali.Rashidi with `from o in objects.Include(x=>x.Nested) let ...` should work.

Comment: This should have more votes since this provides accurate solution without breaking  IQueryable functionality.

Answer (score 4):

Use this overload of select:

```
Obj[] myArray = objects.Select(new Func<Obj,Obj>( o =>
{
    var someLocalVar = o.someVar;

    return new Obj() 
    { 
       Var1 = someLocalVar,
       Var2 = o.var2 
    };
})).ToArray();
```

Comment: This works for me but when used with Entity Framework would this solution prevent the dbcontext from loading all rows into memory first, like AsEnumerable() would?

Comment: @parliament:To prevent loading all rows into memory you should use `Expression<Func<Obj,Obj>>`.

Answer (score 2):

It means that a Lambda expression of type `TDelegate` which contains a `([parameters]) => { some code };` cannot be converted to an `Expression<TDelegate>`.  It's the rule.

Simplify your query.  The one you provided can be rewritten as the following and will compile:

```
Arr[] myArray = objects.Select(o => new Obj()
                {
                   Var1 = o.someVar,
                   Var2 = o.var2
                } ).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `Arr` a base type of `Obj`? Does the Obj class exist? Your code would work only if Arr is a base type of Obj. You can try this instead:

```
Obj[] myArray = objects.Select(o =>
{
    var someLocalVar = o.someVar;

    return new Obj() 
    { 
       Var1 = someLocalVar,
       Var2 = o.var2 
    };
}).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case, the body is for creating a variable, and switching to `IEnumerable` will force all the operations to be processed on client-side, I propose the following solution.

```
Obj[] myArray = objects
.Select(o => new
{
    SomeLocalVar = o.someVar, // You can even use any LINQ statement here
    Info = o,
}).Select(o => new Obj()
{
    Var1 = o.SomeLocalVar,
    Var2 = o.Info.var2,
    Var3 = o.SomeLocalVar.SubValue1,
    Var4 = o.SomeLocalVar.SubValue2,
}).ToArray();
```

Edit: Rename for C# Coding Convention

Answer (score 1):

As stated on other replies, you can only use simple expressions to the right of the `=>` operator. I suggest this solution, which consists of just creating a method that does what you want to have inside of the lambda:

```
public void SomeConfiguration() {
    // ...
    Obj[] myArray = objects.Select(o => Method()).ToArray();
    // ..
}

public Obj Method() {
    var someLocalVar = o.someVar;

    return new Obj() { 
    Var1 = someLocalVar,
    Var2 = o.var2 };
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you came here because this is a top google result for this error but you aren't using a list, you can always do something quick and dirty like this:

my original code:

```
RuleFor(m => m.DocumentName).Must( ...etc...
```

I want to drill into `m` and I know `m` is of type `FileUploadDTO` and in the above expression it is trying to return a string so I add the following method that I can set a breakpoint on:

```
private string GetIt(FileUploadDTO dto)
{
    return dto.FileName;
}
```

Then:

```
RuleFor(m => GetIt(m)).Must( ...etc...
```