# A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, lambda

OK.  So maybe I am lazy.  I don't want to new up an EF object and have to define all of the properties in my linq statement.  This is easy unless you want to modify a property in this object.  In this case, my supplier name property may change based on if the supplier is an agency or a independent contractor.

```
var results = db.tblSuppliers.Select(s => { s.SupplierName = s.CompanyName == null ? s.SupplierFirstName + " " + s.SupplierLastName : s.CompanyName; return s; });

return results.ToList<tblSupplier>();
```

I get the following error:
A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree

I want to return this back as a list of supplier objects.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [“A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5179341/299327)

Answer (score 2):

You have to bring it into memory first and do the projection there - otherwise Linq to Entities will try to convert your projection into a SQL query, for which of course there is no equivalent. You can use `AsEnumerable()` to force the `Select()` projection to be executed in a Linq to Objects context which will then work:

```
var results = db.tblSuppliers
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(s => { s.SupplierName = s.CompanyName == null ? s.SupplierFirstName + " " + s.SupplierLastName : s.CompanyName; return s; })
                .ToList();
```

Second problem is that you cannot project to an entity with EF but using `AsEnumerable()` avoids this problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

`Select` is used for transformation operations. It looks like you just want to mutate the objects by setting the `SupplierName` for each element...

You could use `List.ForEach` to apply the property change you want:

```
var results = db.tblSuppliers.ToList();
results.ForEach(s => s.SupplierName = s.CompanyName == null ? s.SupplierFirstName + " " + s.SupplierLastName : s.CompanyName);
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works, but I realized I need to now join to other tables to get descriptions of the foreign keys in my table.  So really what I want is something like "Select *, desc1, desc2 from table join foreign1... join foreign2.  Now before all you SQL purist pile up on me and lash me for even thinking "select *", I would settle for something that would gen up all the properties I need like sql management studio does when it gens up all the columns in the "script table as.." feature.