# Convert string value to entity in linq where query

Tags: linq, where-clause

I am using jqgrid in MVC 4. I have written a method for getting a list in linq.
In my function I am getting all values of jqgrid with search criteria i.e. Operator AND/OR
, operations Equals to, not equals to etc.  Here I am also getting the column name like Name, City, State etc.

My problem is I can't pass the column name directly in linq query i.e. I have to use the column name as x => x.Name

```
switch (rule.field)
{
    case "Name":
    query = query.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(rule.data, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    break;

    case "Course":
    query = query.Where(x => x.Course.StartsWith(rule.data, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    break;
}
```

In rule.field I am getting column Name i.e. Name, city, state etc.  I want to pass the column name which I am getting in rule.filed in LINQ query instead of `x =>x.Name`.

Is there any way to do it so I can avoid writing switch cases?

Answer (score 0):

You could always use reflection:

```
query = query.ToList().Where(p => {
    var field = p.GetType().GetProperty(rule.field);
    var value = (String) field.GetValue(p);
    return value.StartsWith(rule.data, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
});
```

Warning: Reflection is *slow*. Only use this for short lists. Since you're dealing with UI rendering, I'm assuming this won't be a problem.

**edit:** My example is assuming all properties are indeed properties (and not fields), and that all properties are Strings. You may need to alter the code for your specific case.

Comment: I am getting error like  "A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree"

Comment: Answer modified with `ToList()` to ensure that the query-object is queryable. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179341/a-lambda-expression-with-a-statement-body-cannot-be-converted-to-an-expression for related question if this does not work either. (I don't know what type of object `query` is at your end. I assumed it was some kind of `IQueryable`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Linq.Dynamic, which can be installed as a [Nuget package](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/) along with string.Format. The syntax would then look something like..

```
 var newquery = query.AsQueryable()
            .Where(
                string.Format("{0}.ToUpper().StartsWith(@0)", rule.field)
                    ,rule.data.ToUpper());
```