# Optimize LINQ to SQL statement that has foreign key access

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, optimization

I have the following database diagram:

Each `Product` uses a `LanguageKey` to determine its Name, and each `LanguageKey` has multiple `LanguageValue` records containing value for each language.

[image]

Now in my `Controller`, I want to Select my `Product` entity into the `ViewModel` object, so my statement look like this:

```
 var model = new ProductListViewModel()
        {
            Products = products
                .Select(q => new ProductViewModel()
                {
                    ID = q.ID,
                    Name = q.LanguageKey.LanguageValues.FirstOrDefault(p => p.LanguageID == this.CurrentLanguage.ID && p.Active).Value,
                    Code = q.Code,

                    // Other code
```

So in short, I already have the language ID needed, and I need to get the exact value. However, when looking at the VS's Diagnostic Tools, when the query tree is executed (when I call a `foreach` statement in my View), there are multiple SELECT statement executed by my application, each for one `LanguageValue`, like this:

```
"SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[Active] AS [Active]
    FROM [dbo].[LanguageKey] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @EntityKeyValue1"

"SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[LanguageKeyID] AS [LanguageKeyID], 
    [Extent1].[LanguageID] AS [LanguageID], 
    [Extent1].[Value] AS [Value], 
    [Extent1].[Active] AS [Active]
    FROM [dbo].[LanguageValue] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[LanguageKeyID] = @EntityKeyValue1"
```

Is it because I am using `FirstOrDefault()`? Is there any better way to deal with this, because my application will frequently process around 1k records after filtered.

P.s: I am also wonder why there is no `Active` predicate in the compiled query.

EDIT: This is how I get the `products` (Context is my DbContext, the function is inside `ProductService` class, and `productService` is its instance):

```
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllActiveProducts()
    {
        return this.Context.Products
            .Where(q => q.Active);
    }

    var products = productService.GetAllActiveProducts();
```

Comment: How are you fetching products?

Comment: @PraveenPaulose Sorry I forgot. I added the function and the call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `GetAllActiveProducts()` should return `IQueryable<Product>`, not `IEnumerable<Product>`. By returning `IEnumerable<Product>`, you're effectively forcing any further operations on that enumerable to be done client-side. Which causes exactly the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: OMG I never thought it would be that simple! Thank you very much, everything is done within one SQL call now, and it reduced the query time from 16s to mere 800ms!

Comment: One more question please, sometimes in my `Service` class, I need to use LINQ `Select()` function, which return `IEnumerable` instead of `IQueryable`. How should I deal with it? Does calling `AsQueryable()` after `Select()` help?

Comment: @DatVM LINQ provides `Enumerable.Select` and `Queryable.Select` extension methods. The former takes any `IEnumerable` and returns an `IEnumerable`. The latter takes any `IQueryable` and returns an `IQueryable`. If you're seeing `Select()` returning `IEnumerable`, that's because you're calling the `Enumerable.Select` overload, either because your input is not a queryable, or because your projection is a delegate rather than an expression. (Check the declarations: the projections have different types.) Either way, calling `AsQueryable()` is only very rarely the correct solution.

Comment: I see, thank you very much, it was indeed from `ICollection<>`. I will be working on this then.