# Dynamic Select in Entity Framework Core

Tags: select, dynamic, entity-framework-core, expression

I am creating a procedure that performs a dynamic select of the fields.
For example:

```cs
List<Company> items = await entity
    .Skip(model.Start)
    .Take(model.Length)
    .Select(GenerateDynamicSelect<Company>("Id,Name"))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Company Entity is:

```cs
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    ...others 100 properties...
}

public class Company 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category? Category { get; set; }
    public string? Code { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    ...others 100 properties...
}
```

everything works fine if I use

```cs
GenerateDynamicSelect<Company>("Id,Name")
```

But how do I use nested fields?

```cs
GenerateDynamicSelect<Company>("Id,Name,Category.Name")
```

It is important to avoid loading all the columns of the Category table.

The code i wrote:

```cs
private static Expression<Func<T, T>> GenerateDynamicSelect<T>(string fields)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
    NewExpression objToInitialise = Expression.New(type);
    HashSet<string> parsedColumns = new();

    BindingFlags searchFlags = BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
    IEnumerable<MemberAssignment> bindings = fields.Split(',')
        .Select(columnName => columnName.Trim().ToLower())
        .Where(columnName => !parsedColumns.Contains(columnName))
        .Select(columnName =>
            {
                parsedColumns.Add(columnName);
                PropertyInfo? property;
                if (columnName.Contains('.'))
                {
                    string[] parts = columnName.Split('.');
                    property = type.GetProperty(parts[0], searchFlags);

                    how i can do?
                }
                else
                {
                    property = type.GetProperty(columnName, searchFlags);
                }
                MemberExpression originalValue = Expression.Property(parameter, property);
                return Expression.Bind(property, originalValue);
            }
        );
    MemberInitExpression initializedMember = Expression.MemberInit(objToInitialise, bindings);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(initializedMember, parameter);
}
```

Thanks. I use .NET 6

Comment: I think this function should do that for you, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66334073/10646316)

Comment: I finally solved it with the help of this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53500412/write-dynamic-linq-queries-for-sorting-and-projecting-with-ef-core.
Thank you all