# C# LINQ query to data from multiple tables

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have 2 tables:

`Metrics` (id, Metric) :[{1,Metric1},{2,Metric2},{3,Metric3}]

```
id | Metric
------------------------------------------------------------
1  |  Metric1
2  |  Metric2
3  |  Metric3
```

`MetricsValuePerPerson` (id, PersonId, Metricid, Value)

```
id | PersonId | Metricid | Value
------------------------------------------------------------
1  |  1       |     1    |  P1metric1Value
2  |  1       |     2    |  P1Metric2Value
3  |  1       |     3    |  P1metric3Value
4  |  2       |     1    |  P2Metric1Value
5  |  2       |     2    |  P2metric2Value
6  |  2       |     3    |  P2Metric3Value
```

I want to show the values in a grid where each row is a `Person` and each column is a `Metric`:

```
PersonId | Metric1         | Metric2        | Metric3
------------------------------------------------------------
P1       |  P1metric1Value | P1Metric2Value | P1Metric3Value
P2       |  P2metric1Value | P2Metric2Value | P2Metric3Value
```

Here is how I try to load the store:

```
var metricValues = from mv in dc.MetricsValuePerPerson
                   join m in dc.Metrics on mv.Metricid equals m.id
                   select new { Personid = mv.Personid, Metric1 = (codesnippet) , Metric2 = (codesnippet), Metric3 = (codesnippet) };
```

How can I replace `(codesnippet)` to get the `Value` of `Metricx`?

Comment: 'each row is a Person and each column is a Metric' - Is it means, your First Column is Person and rest of the columns are Metrics? Is there only 3 metrics?

Comment: @SelvaTS yes for the columns, there are multiple metrics not just 3 but are known

Comment: It means you have to transpose related rows as columns.

Comment: Using my code you can get same result try it

Answer (score 0):

In LINQ, provided you have established relations in the database, you very rarely need to use JOIN keyword. In your case, within the DB you have relation between MetricsValuesPerPerson and Metrics, right? If so then:

```
var metricValues = from mv in dc.MetricsValuePerPerson
                   select new { 
                    Personid = mv.Personid, 
                    Metric1 = mv.Metric.Metric };
```

The result doesn't seem to be meaningful though (probably you would want to add Value too).

EDIT: This would be like a pivot, assuming you only have 3 metrics and at most 1 from each type of metric per person (ie: there is no personId, metricId, value like (1,1,10) and (1,1,20).

```
var result = from mv in MetricsValuePerPersons.Where(mvpp => mvpp.Metricid == 1)
                 let mv2 = MetricsValuePerPersons.SingleOrDefault(mvpp => mvpp.PersonId == mv.PersonId && mvpp.Metricid == 2)
                 let mv3 = MetricsValuePerPersons.SingleOrDefault(mvpp => mvpp.PersonId == mv.PersonId && mvpp.Metricid == 3)
                 select new {
        PersonId = mv.PersonId,
        Metric1 = mv.Value,
        Metric2 = mv2.Value,
        Metric3 = mv3.Value,
    };
```

Comment: indeed, if you see the last line of my post I need the value of the metric

Comment: @aggicd, Value of metric is in the other table and doesn't need a join.

Comment: I need the name of the metric which is stored in `Metrics` table

Comment: @aggicd, Would you please supply sample input data and how the output looks like.

Comment: Please check original post

Comment: @aggicd, Oh now I see you are after something like "pivot". IMHO it is not easy with LINQ and I would do that in backend. If your metrics are constantly 3 (like an enum) then you can do something like in the edited post.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `GroupJoin` (equivalent to `LEFT JOIN` in SQL). Join the  `MetricsValuePerPerson` with `Metrics` and then `GroupBy` by the `PersonId` then `Select` the result. The sample code is in `Lambda Join`, but you can convert this to `LINQ`.

Working sample : [C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3sl45C)

```
var result = metricValuePerPerson.GroupJoin(metrics, mv => new { Id = mv.PersonId }, m => new { Id = m.Id }, 
        (mv, m) => new { mv = mv, m = m })
        .SelectMany(x => x.m.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, y) => new {mv = x.mv, m = y })
        .GroupBy(g => g.mv.PersonId)
        .Select(x =>  
        {
           var grouped = x.ToList();
           return new 
            {
                PersonId = x.Key, //The below are sample code, please use your actual code.
                Metric1 = grouped[0].mv.PersonId + "|" + grouped[0].m.Metric + "|" + grouped[0].mv.Value,
                Metric2 = grouped[1].mv.PersonId + "|" + grouped[1].m.Metric + "|" + grouped[1].mv.Value,
                Metric3 = grouped[2].mv.PersonId + "|" + grouped[2].m.Metric + "|" + grouped[2].mv.Value,
            };
        })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: I get this error : A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree in the `.Select(x =>

Comment: @aggicd I think you are directly using `IQueryable` object. You have to convert it into `List` before Join. Refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5179417/311255