# Auto populate properties in class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Suppose that I have a class name User, is there any ways to populate the class properties and default value in Visual Studio as follow. I feel it is tedious to repeat typing the properties again and again.

Probably there is default shortcut to do this in Visual Studio or any extension that can do this?

**Case 1**

```
var user = db.User.Where(x => x.UserID).Select(o => new User
{
   UserId = o.UserId, // auto populate
   Username = o.Username, // auto populate
   ........  // auto populate all properties inside User class
}
);
```

**case 2**

```
var user = new User();
user.UserID = "",  // auto populate with type default value
user.Username = "",  // auto populate with type default value
........ // auto populate all properties inside User class
........ // auto populate all properties inside User class
```

Comment: What's wrong with setting their default value in the default constructor?

Comment: `new User();` will populate the properties with the type's default value already. Note that `""` is _not_ the default value of a `string`. A `string` is a reference type, so its default value is `null`.

Comment: As for case 1, just drop the entire .Select and you'll get the enumerable of Users, or create a dedicated Clone() if you want to duplicate them instead.

Comment: @Martheen for case 1 sometimes the User class does not map to db.User (eg, i might need an additional field to User class on top of properties value return in db.User, eg: age which is not return from the database) where in such cases i need to retype the property 1 by 1 again. What do you mean by dedicated clone and how that could be done

Comment: The expression doesn't have to be a single statement. Select(o=> { var d = o.Clone(); d.NewProperty = newValue; return d;} works.

Comment: A dedicated clone is just that. User Clone() => return new User {UserId=this.UserID; ...}

Comment: For case 1, perhaps a library such as AutoMapper might be what you want? You could then do something like `var users = _mapper.Map<IList<User>>(db.user.Where(query));`. For case 2, why not just set the default when you define the property? For example: `public string Username {get;set;} = "Bob";`, and then if you don't assign a value to it it will be "Bob".

Comment: @Llama yes for case 1 probably i think i can use automapper

Comment: @Martheen Clone() is not a function is that any library that I need to import?

Comment: Either write it yourself, or if both the User from DB and the User you want is the same class, use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=net-5.0

Comment: @Martheen the solution u proposed for case 1 does not work i got error `A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree`. Seems that it cannot be used for linq to sql context https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179341/a-lambda-expression-with-a-statement-body-cannot-be-converted-to-an-expression It is AsEnumerable() and i do not want it to change it to ToList() before select as it will impact performance (as i need to do pagination). cannot afford to query whole list from database.

Comment: This sounds like something that "automapper" would happily do for you

Comment: @MarcGravell AutoMapper does not work for case 1, at least not in AsQueryable()

Comment: @eulercode Do the [Queryable Extensions](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html) help?

Comment: @Llama cool i will look at the queryable extensions

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what are you trying to achieve here

```
var user = db.User.Where(x => x.UserID).Select(o => new User
{
  UserId = o.UserId, // auto populate
  Username = o.Username, // auto populate
  ........  // auto populate all properties inside User class
}
```

since both `new User` and `db.User` are the same type of class/entity. But let's say you have an entity model `User` and a DTO/View model called `UserViewModel` and you want automatically to map the values of `User` to `UserViewModel` you can use automapper https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html Example this is the Entity definition

```
public class User 
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
  
   public string FirstName {get; set;}

   public string LastName {get; set;}
 
   public int Age {get; set;}
}
```

And we have a `UserViewModel` to which you want to map the data from `User`

```
  public class UserViewModel 
  {
     public int Id {get; set;}
  
     public string FirstName {get; set;}

     public string LastName {get; set;}
 
     public int Age {get; set;}
   }
```

With `AutoMapper` you can do this

```
 var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(config =>
 {
     config.CreateMap<User, UserViewModel>();
 }
```

and then you can use the mapper configuration like this

```
var user = db.User.Where(x => x.UserID).First();
var userViewModel = configuration.CreateMapper().Map<UserViewModel>(user);
```

This will automatically populate the property values of `User` to `UserViewModel`. Alternatively you can have a view model like this

```
public class UserViewModel 
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
  
     public string FullName {get; set;}
 
     public int Age {get; set;}
}
```

This time not all properties of `User` and `UserViewModel` match one to one and you will have to set a custom mapper configuration i.e.

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(config =>
 {
     config.CreateMap<User, UserViewModel>()
           .ForMember(uvm => uvm.FullName, o => o.MapFrom($"{u.FirstName} {u.LastName}") );
 }
```

This way you are configuring the automatic `User` to `UserViewModel` mapping to map the `FullName` property value by concatenating `FirstName` and `LastName` from `User`

Answer (score 0):

Well I have build a library that could solve this problem for you, called [FastDeepCloner](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastDeepCloner/)

```js
   public class User 
    {

        public virtual string Name { get; set; } = "sdjh";

        public virtual int PasswordLength { get; set; } = 6;

        public Circular Test { get; set; } = new Circular();

    }
    
    public class CloneToTest
    {
        [FastDeepCloner.FastDeepClonerColumn("Name")] 
        [FastDeepCloner.FastDeepClonerColumn("LastName")] // Or
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        
        // You see here the type could be difrrent then the orginal type. 
        // FastDeepCloner will try to convert it, if it fail then a default value will be inserted insted
        public string PasswordLength { get; set; }
        
        // You could add a path insted, remember this only work on none list items.
        [FastDeepClonerColumn("Test.myBar.Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Circular Test { get; set; }
    }
```

Now simple use

```
  var user = new User() { Name = "alen toma" };
        var cloneTo =new  CloneToTest();

        FastDeepCloner.DeepCloner.CloneTo(user, cloneTo);
  
        Assert.AreEqual(user.Name, cloneTo.FullName);
```